# `pipenv install` timing out on RPi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pexpect, pipenv

I'm trying to bring up `[pipenv][1]` on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.  The symptom I'm seeing is that pexpect times out when trying to [create a tutorial project](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/install/#installing-packages-for-your-project).

Admittedly, the RPi is a small machine, but I was monitoring memory usage and swap space during the process, and it wasn't running out of memory or swap.

Any idea what it was trying to do?  Or how I should debug this?  Here's the stack trace:

```
pi@blue-server:~/testdir $ pipenv install requests
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.5.3) to create virtualenv…
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/expect.py", line 109, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/expect.py", line 82, in timeout
    raise TIMEOUT(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0xb555c950>
searcher: searcher_re:
0: EOF

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 478, in uninstall
    keep_outdated=keep_outdated,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2077, in do_uninstall
    ensure_project(three=three, python=python)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 620, in ensure_project
    three=three, python=python, site_packages=site_packages
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 569, in ensure_virtualenv
    do_create_virtualenv(python=python, site_packages=site_packages)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 936, in do_create_virtualenv
    click.echo(crayons.blue(c.out), err=True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/delegator.py", line 99, in out
    self.__out = self._pexpect_out
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/delegator.py", line 87, in _pexpect_out
    result += self.subprocess.read()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 441, in read
    self.expect(self.delimiter)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 341, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 369, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/expect.py", line 119, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/expect.py", line 82, in timeout
    raise TIMEOUT(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0xb553a710>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: EOF
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0xb553a710>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: EOF
```

Here's the environment info:

```
pi@blue-server:~/foo $ uname -a
Linux blue-server 4.14.34+ #1110 Mon Apr 16 14:51:42 BST 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux

pi@blue-server:~/foo $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
Release:    9.4
Codename:   stretch

pi@blue-server:~/foo $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

pi@blue-server:~/foo $ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            433          26         260           3         145         353
Swap:            99           0          99
```

### additional info

I noticed it was timing out inside of a subprocess call.  Using pdb, I traced it down to the command:

```
<Command ['/usr/bin/python3.5', '-m', 'pipenv.pew', 'new', 'foo-su43ObVR', '-d', '-p', '/usr/bin/python3.5']>
```

I tried replicating that call from the command line and it completed without error:

```
pi@blue-server:~/foo $ /usr/bin/python3.5 -m pipenv.pew new 'asdf' -d -p /usr/bin/python3.5
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/pi/.local/share/virtualenvs/asdf/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /home/pi/.local/share/virtualenvs/asdf/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

That seems hopeful, but I still don't know what causes the timeout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TL;DR: the fix is to extend the timeout

Solved it.  Because the RPi Zero is slow, it was timing out.  Taking a clue [from the discussion on github](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/401), I noticed that its now possible to extend the default timeout with environment variables. So this solved the problem:

```
pi@blue-server:~/testdir $ export PIPENV_TIMEOUT=500
pi@blue-server:~/testdir $ pipenv install requests
```

Comment: Can't believe how many times I've given up after getting that error. THANK YOU!!!